# php.ini - настройки почты Яндекс

Tags: php, email, php.ini, яндекс-почта

Пробую отправлять почту через Яндекс из PHP:

```
<?php
    $message = "Проверочное сообщение (тело)";
    $result = mail( 'aaaa@gmail.com', 'Тема - проверочное письмо', $message );
    echo "result: $result";
?>
```

Настройка `php.ini` (Windows):

```
SMTP = smtp.yandex.ru
smtp_port = 465
username = info@pdd-yandex.ru
password = password1
sendmail_from = info@pdd-yandex.ru
mail.log = syslog
```

Не происходит ничего, `$result` пустой.
Да, я знаю, что в Яндексе нужно еще установить защиту SSL (во всяком случае, для почтовых приложений), но какие параметры php.ini при этом настраивать - непонятно. В `syslog` при этом только строка из To: `aaaa@gmail.com` и пустым `headers`.

Comment: Если вы впервые пытаетесь отправить письмо через этот адрес на яндексе, то для активации ящика сначала нужно выполнить обычный вход через веб-интерфейс.

Comment: А веб-сервер у вас какой?